# How to push a DIV down when another one opens?

Tags: html, css

Heyy.

I've been trying to figure this out and I've looked all over but so far nothing's worked so I thought maybe you could help me out.

I'm working on a new tumblr theme with masonry and I want the post captions to slide down when a post is hovered on. I got that bit working but the problem is the post underneath the one hovered won't be pushed down when the caption opens, and that means that bigger captions will be hidden behind that post.

Here's the code I have:

```
.c220 {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
}

.p200:hover .c220 {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}
```

And here's the link to see it live: https://thm-maddison.tumblr.com/

The captions I have aren't too big so they don't get hidden but I'd like the post below them to be pushed down about 60px if that's possible.

Thank you for your help and I wish you all a great 2017!

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this without applying `position: absolute;` to the `<article class="p200...` elements. Absolutely positioned elements are outside of the html element flow.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have no `position:absolute` though :/

Comment: I believe it's being added via js. I'll update my post with a screenshot.

Comment: I see it now. I think it's from the masonry script. There's probably no way around it because if I remove the absolute positioning the masonry doesn't work.

Comment: @Sol that is very likely. If you just want to preserve the captions and make sure they're visible, just add a higher z-index to the article on hover.